# ios5 storyboard application for ios4

Tags: iphone, ios5, compatibility, storyboard

I am creating a new application and am planning to start with `ios5` as it supports `storyboards`. However, I am not sure if the app that is compiled with `ios5` runs on `ios4` as we are looking at kind of a forward compatibility. Since `ARC` is a compile time feature, I am guessing that is not a problem. However, the calls like `prepareForSegue` or `performSegueWithIdentifier` depend on `ios5` api's. However as the code is built, I am wondering if the executable assembly is capable of running on `ios4` devices. Can some please shed some light on this?

Also, if the answer is a strict NO, do I need to go back with traditional `NIB`'s for the app? Are there any selective features that may work and that may not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `UIStoryboardSegue` is iOS 5 only, thus the app will not run on iOS 4. Since it not a compile time feature, you will have to go back to using `NIB`'s.

Any methods you use that are only available in iOS 5 will not work in iOS 4, thus meaning that any methods that deal with the storyboard will not work in iOS 4.

Comment: Hmm, means I need to go back to traditional XIB's to make sure this app is backward compatible. Am guessing I can use ARC though..